# Can I say "I was surfing Facebook and I found a video of a citizen shouting at a police officer"?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Is the expression "surfing Facebook" something native English speakers use in their talk?

Comment: We normally talk about "surfing" ***the entire Internet***, but I don't see why you shouldn't be able to restrict your "aimless browsing" to just Facebook or Youtube or whatever. But seriously, apart from newspaper hacks, does anyone *actually* use the word ***surfing*** like this? Don't we all just ***go online***, and maybe ***browse*** the Internet today?

Comment: searching on FB, search for x on FB.

Comment: the meaning I wanna imply is "I'm taking a break from studying and want to use Facebook for no specific purpose .. just casually .. killing the time"

Comment: Please use want to and not wanna when writing. Sure, playing around on FB.

Answer (score 2):

You can say that, See for example : [Top 15 reasons you're surfing facebook](https://www.socialmediatoday.com/content/surf-web-or-surf-facebook-top-15-reasons-why-youre-surfing-facebook)

However it is much less common than "surfing the web". In any case it means moving from one page to another, following hyperlinks not using search or google or a plan. (Analogous to the way that a surfer picks up one wave after another, without a plan)

Comment: Thank U @James K !

The place where I'm from doesn't usually surf the web. Instead, people most of the time only surf Facebook -which is not something beneficial but that's it anyway, just stating facts !"